# Twitter API / Following someone

Tags: twitter, sttwitterapi

Is that possible that website users follows our vendors twitter account using API on our web? I want to add vendors twitter follow button on our vendor page and if users click the button on our web, users can follow their vendors twitter account.

Comment: You can add "follow buttons" : https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [Twitter Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents)

The easiest way to do this is to write a link like https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=edent

If you click on that, you'll be prompted to follow me.  Just change `edent` to the name of the Twitter account you want people to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an HTML snippet to add a [Follow button](https://publish.twitter.com/?buttonType=FollowButton) to a website via [Twitter Publish](http://publish.twitter.com).